# Is bitcode required in order to allow users to download only the executable architecture needed for the target device?

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, app-store, bitcode

My app size is huge, almost 100MB for an ordinary Mahjong game made with Unity3D. I'd like to provide smaller downloads for my audience.

Most of the problem comes from the **executable** code embedded in the fat binary (`armv7` and `arm64` architectures). I don't use a lot of images and using On Demand resources/levels does not make much sense in my game.

Looks like `App Slicing` feature from Apple is the way to go, since it allows `iOS 9` users to download from the App Store the app variant containing only the executable architecture needed for the target device.

Since I'm using 3rd party frameworks that don't support bitcode, me question is:

1. Is bitcode support **required** for my purposes? Does the App Store **require** bitcode in order to 'slice' my app for `iOS 9` users?
2. In case bitcode is not required, do I need to set my deployment target to `iOS 9` or can I still support `iOS >= 7` and take advantage of `App Slicing` for the `iOS 9` users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) As you can see in the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) App Slicing and Bitcode are two different things so yeah, it will work iOS9 users

2) Same link

> Note: Sliced apps are supported on devices running 9.0 and later; otherwise, the store delivers universal apps to customers.

So you can continue to target iOS7, Apple will do the job

N.